# VanillaJs with Webpack, can't load bundle.js in index.html after build

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Running On The webpac-dev-server, My app works fine.

But After building with web pack, run index.html from the public folder and you can't get Bundle.js. With this error,

**unexpected token '<'  bundle.js line 1**

my webpack conf file is

```
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'none',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3001,
    hot: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname),
        exclude: /(node_modules)|(public)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html',
    }),
  ],
};
```

and Here is my folder tree structure

[image]

After build, index.html in public folder not working (can't load bundle.js)

but webpack-dev-server working well.

Comment: Could you share your index.html with us ?

Comment: @ismetguzelgun  sure `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Word Game</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
    </div>
  <script src="bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
` here it is very simple (after build)

Answer (score 0):

You should use / before bundle.js `<script src="/bundle.js"></script>` Your output is looking fine. Other than that there is another solution i find you might want to try.

```
> added <base href="/" /> into the <head> of my index.html
```

[github](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2882)

Comment: okay, I've already tried everything. ex) bundle.js, /bundle.js, ./bundle.js . but Not Working And It is output of webpack build

Comment: Edited answer. Check it out.